# Multi node search in a single cypherQuery of Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to do multi node in a single cyperQuery statement of Neo4j as shown in non functioning cyperQuery statement in .NET

```
string cypherQuery = String.Format(@" 
    START r=node:node_auto_index(""name:(*{0}*)""),
          re=node:node_auto_index(""name:(*{0}*)""),
          d=node:node_auto_index(""name:(*{0}*)"") 
    MATCH (o:Origin{name:{OriginatedFromOrigin}})<-[:ORIGINATED_FROM]-(d:Domain)
          -[:HAS_ROLE]->(r:Role)
          -[rel:HAS_RESPONSIBILITY]->(re:Responsibility),
         (resOriginatedFromOrigin:Origin{name:{OriginatedFromOrigin}})
            <-[:ORIGINATED_FROM]-(re:Responsibility) 
     RETURN ID(r) AS RID, r.name AS RName, ID(re) AS ResID,
            rel.weightinrole AS WeightInRole,
            rel.percenttimeinrole AS PercentTimeInRole,re.name AS ResName,
            re.description AS ResDesc,
            ID(resOriginatedFromOrigin) AS ResOriginatedFromOriginID,               
            resOriginatedFromOrigin.name AS ResOriginatedFromOrigin ",

     request.SearchText);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Michael Hunger,by multi node I mean in the single cyperQuery above in "START Clause"  there are three nodes (node "r" for Role,node "re" for Responsibility,node "d" for Domain) together, I want to perform search on "name" of the three  "nodes" in a single cyperQuery,I will be very grateful to you if you take time out to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual question?

You should probably update to a recent Neo4j version first if you're beginner. The start clauses are from Neo4j 1.9 which is like 3 years old.

And you can use Neo4jClient or Cypher.NET clients to send Cypher queries to Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's,Michale Hunger, going to latest version of Neo4j solved my problem.